# Why is this Illegal Character Exception not being resolved to a type?

Tags: java, exception, illegal-characters

For an assignment, I have to enter a string and reverse it, while throwing an Illegal Character Exception if a character in the string is not a letter, digit, or white space. My professor says that there no method throw clauses are needed.

Here is my code

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
public class reverse3
{
   public static void reverse(String x)
   {
      char j;
      String reversedString;
      for(int i = 0; i < x.length(); i++)
      {
         try
         {
           if(!Character.isDigit(x.charAt(i)) && !Character.isLetter(x.charAt(i)) && !Character.isWhitespace(x.charAt(i)))
         {
            throw ( new IllegalCharacterException("Illegal Character in String"));
         }//end if
         else if(Character.isDigit(x.charAt(i)) && Character.isLetter(x.charAt(i)) && Character.isWhitespace(x.charAt(i)))
         {
            j = x.charAt(i);
            j = reversedString.charAt(i - 1);
         }//end else if
       }//end try
     catch(IllegalCharacterException e)
     {
       System.out.println(e.getMessage());
     }//end catch
   }//end for loop
}//end method

 public static void main(String[] args)
 {
   Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
   String s;
   System.out.println("Please enter a string");
   s = keyboard.next();
   reverse(s);
 }//end main
}//end class
```

I keep getting this error at line 15 and 23
    Error: IllegalCharacterException cannot be resolved to a type

Comment: Did you define your own `IllegalCharacterException` exception class?

Comment: You need to import it probably.

Comment: In your catch you could do `catch(Exception e){ e.printStackTrace(); }` and that would tell you what's going on.  Catching Exception e catches all possible exceptions

Comment: @Joris OP is getting a compilation error. On the other hand `e.printStackTrace()` is always an improvement over `System.out.println(e.getMessage())`...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you're looking for [`IllegalArgumentException`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/lang/IllegalArgumentException.java#IllegalArgumentException)

```
new IllegalArgumentException("Illegal Character in String"));
```

> Thrown to indicate that a method has been passed an illegal or
>   inappropriate argument.

---

Otherwise, you can define your own class if you want but I don't see the added-value since the message of `IllegalArgumentException` can be customized.

```
public class IllegalCharacterException extends Exception {

    public IllegalCharacterException(String msg) {
        super(msg);
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it just fixed

Answer (score 1):

your code needs `else` block also.
because in your code `else if` portion, at a time 3 types can't match.

And `Illegal Character Exception` is actually `IllegalArgumentException`. If you want to specify actual issue then you can use `IllegalArgumentException`. On the other hand you can use `Exception` also.